# Test to examine difference

Tags: anova, t-test, repeated-measures

I am trying to investigate the prevalence of aggressive driving. So my objective is to see if the proportion of the aggressive trip (with at least one aggressive event) or aggressive trip per driven mile is different between weekday/weekend; morning/afternoon; urban/rural trips and also male/female. I have data from 50 participants for 3 months with no control group or base condition.

I know I can see male/female or age differences using the t-test. Can I use repeated measure ANOVA or dependent t-test to test weekday/weekend or morning afternoon? What is the difference?